# Objects appear before NLA actions

Tags: animation

i have 2 objects moving. Id like the third object to come in later in the scene. This object has its actions set to start at a different frame. However i still see object being idle. How do i set an object to appear in my scene once their animations starts?

Comment: you need to create the animation of the third object, then push it down into the NLA, and move the NLA strip where the action is supposed to begin.

Comment: yes I have this animation but its still in the camera view, once the timeline reaches the NLA action it moves and does what it needs to. What I am asking is, how do I make the entire object only appear when timeline reaches the NLA action. Right now it stays idle and then moves once timeline reaches the NLA strip

Comment: appear meaning it is invisible or it moves? If you want it invisible, create some keyframes on the Outliner render visibility icon

Comment: Ok for example... i have a man flying with fire coming out of his hands. Once he lands i want the fireballs gone completely.. how do i rid this?